# How to Fill Down using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is there a function to fill down a column? I am trying to write a formula into C2 and then want it to fill down to the end of the data. I feel that there is an easy way to do this, but I haven't found anything through googling yet. Any help is appreciated!

```
worksheet.write(1,2, '=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("21",B2)),"x","")')
```

That is the code that I have to fill C2 with. Then I want that formula to fill down adjusting the B2 as it fill down. Just as it would if you double-clicked the bottom right corner of the cell in excel.

Comment: What format is your data in?  You need to give more info if you want assistance...Sample code would be nice as well.

Comment: I added more information; it is a fairly straightforward question. I just can't seem to find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: you could do this much easier in pandas - it has a forward fill method (df.ffill) and has a write to excel method (df.to_excel).  I asked to see if you already had the data in pandas.  If not, might not hurt to convert to pandas dataframe, then apply those two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a simple loop and one of the XlsxWriter [utility](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions) functions:

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row_num in range(1, 10):
    cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row_num, 1)
    formula = '=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("21",%s)),"x","")' % cell
    worksheet.write(row_num, 2, formula)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: I decided to go with this solution shortly after posting. A bit thrown together in my opinion but it gets the job done well.